# Flutter: How to display info in a Chat UI from top to bottom using ListView.builder

Tags: flutter

I am creating a chat UI and would like the newer message to show up reverse order. However, I want the chat text to start from the top of UI and not the bottom

The message order is working .How do I get the message to display from top of the UI instead of the bottom

So, basically I want the message to start below "my chat title"

Thanks for your help

code snippet

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text("Flutter Facts"),
      ),
      body: Column(children: <Widget>[
        Container(
         margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 30.0, 0.0, 0),
         padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
         width: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith().size.width ,
         decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(width:1),),
  
         child:Text('My chat')
        ),
        Flexible(
            child: ListView.builder(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              reverse: true, //To keep the latest messages at the bottom
              itemBuilder: (_, int index) => _messages[index],
              itemCount: _messages.length,
            ),),
        Divider(height: 1.0),
        Container(
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Theme.of(context).cardColor),
          child: _queryInputWidget(context),
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
```

[image]

I tried setting the reverse to false.. This position the text correctly but now the newer message are on top. The order in not maintain (older ->newer)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `reverse` parameter of the `Listview.builder` is for setting the place (top or bottom) where the items get displayed. If it's set to `true`, the items will be displayed on bottom instead of top. So you just need to remove the `reverse: true`.

> To keep the latest messages at the bottom

Because the items are displayed with respect to their index, the latest messages will be displayed at the bottom no matter the `reverse` is `true` or `false`. The `reverse` parameter has nothing to do with the order of the items inside the list.
If the messages are not sorted, you can sort them by time.

If the messages are displayed in reverse order, you can do:

```
_messages = _messaged.reversed.toList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi just `set reverse: true` to  `false` in `ListView.builder`. That should do it.
Let me know..
Cheers.

Comment: Thanks .. if I do that the message are not sorted correctly.. I want the order to stay the same (older message first)..

Comment: Sure if you also want your List to be displayed the other way around then you shiuld also reverse the List itself as the accepted answer. Glad you solved it. Cheers